# Does Harkness ever use an Infiltrator?

Tags: fallout-shelter, fallout-3

I got [Harkness](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Harkness) in a lunch box in my Fallout Shelter game.

He came with an [infiltrator](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Infiltrator_%28Fallout_3%29), not a sick plasma rifle like [the one he's known for](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/A3-21's_plasma_rifle). This seems odd.

Is there any association between Harkness and the Infiltrator, or any assault rifle for that matter, in Fallout lore? This could be in game, or in associated media.

Comment: Likely because that's how the game devs felt like creating him. (aka we are really unlikely to know for sure, unless we get very lucky and they've explained it somewhere).

Comment: @DCShannon, actually; yes it is. Perhaps they used the wrong words, but that's the point: without word from the devs, we can't answer your question.

Comment: I noticed on the fallout wikia that Harkness has a Chinese Assault Rifle in his inventory, so I think my guess about the reason is actually probably correct. Would be nice to be able to post that as an answer.

Comment: People playing the game might know him for using a plasma rifle, but Harkness himself doesn't actually use it. It was probably impractical for day to day policing of Rivet City, with ammo being cost-prohibitive compared to cheaper options like the assault rifle. Note that he states he's "had it for a long as [he] can remember", not that he uses it every day. Remember that Fallout is a game of scavenging - I wouldn't think of any singular character as being "known" for the weapon they wield.

Comment: @Robotnik That's a fair point, except the main reason anyone interacts with Harkness is to get the awesome quest reward, which is his plasma rifle (and a perk, if  you do it right).

Comment: @DCShannon - sure, but that doesn't mean it's **his** weapon of choice.

Comment: @Robotnik Right, which appears to be the answer.

Comment: @Robotnik You wouldn't remember Boone and his trusty sniper rifle? Or Cass and her revolvers?  Despite the character being able to change an NPC's gun used, they will always have a "signature" weapon that defines them. Dr. Gannon's theme is energy guns, the list goes on.

Comment: @oamlyya - OP wanted an in-canon answer, what you're describing is player knowledge. I'm not disputing the fact Harkness is 'known' for his plasma rifle, I'm explaining why *in game*, this doesn't make sense, and why he may be using a different weapon.

Comment: @Robotnik I'm sorry, I was addressing your "I wouldn't think of any singular character as being "known" for the weapon they wield; guess I shoulda made that clearer.

Comment: @Robotnik I think I might have figured out where the confusion is here. It may be true that characters such as Harkness and Boone won't be known for a weapon *in-universe* among the other characters, but they *are* known for specific weapons among players. So while whether he uses an assault rifle or not would require an answer based on the situation in-universe, that has nothing to do with whether he's known for the weapon or not. *I* was surprised, because *I* know him for his plasma rifle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the inventory section of the [Harkness page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Harkness) on the the Fallout Wikia, it lists the Chinese Assault Rifle as his weapon, not the plasma rifle.

There is also a screenshot, which appears to show such an assault rifle on his back.

So, although Harkness may have used his plasma rifle as his primary weapon in the past, it is not the weapon he is using by the time we meet him in Rivet City.

As far as him using an *Infiltrator* in Fallout Shelter, it is worth noting that there is no [Chinese Assault Rifle in Fallout Shelter](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_weapons), and that the Infiltrator is simply the best version of the assault rifle in that game.